# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras' WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -rotobuf in cmd

Tags: tensorflow

`tensorflow                   2.11.0`
`keras                        2.11.0`
`pip                          22.3.1`
`Python 3.9.1`

help me please, i want to run tensorflow.keras but error

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.applications import MobileNetV2
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
```

`

`

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [8], line 2
      1 import tensorflow as tf
----> 2 from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
      3 from tensorflow.keras.applications import MobileNetV2
      4 from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras'
```

`

i already install tf, keras, i already upgrade version, downgrade version but same, my terminal

`WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -rotobuf (c:\users\fast\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages) WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -rotobuf (c:\users\fast\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages) Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\fast\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (22.3.1) WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -rotobuf (c:\users\fast\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages) WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -rotobuf (c:\users\fast\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages) WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -rotobuf (c:\users\fast\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages) WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -rotobuf (c:\users\fast\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages)`

i already upgrade version tf and keras but same

Comment: Could you please check again and let us know with few more details like what steps you have followed to install the tensorflow if the issue still persists. What is the output for `import tensorflow as tf`, `tf.__version__`.